# To get lnoremap (with L) to work

Tags: vim

Is there any special precondition that needs to be set for `lnoremap` (`l` being the important thing here) to work?

I have used map for sometime to generally swap the number keys and their symbols (since the symbols are written much more often). I had successfully used `noremap` and `noremap!` to swap those keys without a problem.

I had noticed that the mapping didn't take effect with `f`. Recently I learned about `r` and see that the mapping doesn't take effect with that either. From the help of `mapmode-l`:

```
Some commands work both in Insert mode and Command-line mode, some not:

    commands:                                 modes: ~
                                          Insert  Command-line  Lang-Arg ~
:map!  :noremap!  :unmap!  :mapclear!       yes        yes         -
:imap  :inoremap  :iunmap  :imapclear       yes         -          -
:cmap  :cnoremap  :cunmap  :cmapclear        -         yes         -
:lmap  :lnoremap  :lunmap  :lmapclear       yes*       yes*       yes*
```

and later continues (in `language-mapping`):

```
":lmap" defines a mapping that applies to:
- Insert mode
- Command-line mode
- when entering a search pattern
- the argument of the commands that accept a text character, such as "r" and
  "f"
- for the input() line
```

which seems the perfect mapping type. Since `lnoremap` is supposed to also map for Insert and Command-line, I tried replacing `noremap!` with `lnoremap`. The result is that neither Lang-Arg, nor Insert, nor Command-line have that mapping anymore.

My question is, is there something specific I need to set before `lnoremap` could be used? What's with those `*`s next to the `yes`es of `lnoremap`? Does that mean the "yes" is conditioned to something? To what if so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can toggle the use of language mappings on/off via `<C-^>` in insert mode, or globally enable it via

```
:set iminsert=1
```

See `:help i_CTRL-^` and `:help 'iminsert'` for a detailed explanation. The reason for this toggling is that some users only want the language mappings (or overall keymap for a particular language) applied in certain situations.

For command-line mode, you also need

```
:set imcmdline
```

Comment: Thanks! This made it work with Insert mode and `f` and `r`, but it doesn't work for command line. I added `cnoremap` to complete it (but still don't know why `lnoremap` didn't do `cnoremap` by itself!)

Comment: @Shahbaz random guess: try setting `'imcmdline'`

Comment: @mMontu, actually it didn't work (even though I found `set imsearch=1` (or -1) which fixed it for Search. (I'm using vim 7.3 and unfortunately under windows). Anyway, `cnoremap` fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok it seems that, that's not all. If I record a macro in which I enter one of those keys in insert mode, or use it after `f`, replaying the macro uses the original key instead of the mapped one. Using them after `d` for example doesn't have this problem. When I used to have `inoremap` in the past, this didn't happen. So it seems that `lnoremap` with `iminsert=1` isn't exactly the same as `inoremap`.

Comment: @Shahbaz I'd try on a newer version, there is a chance that it works better. I'm using a Vim 7.4 -- if you provide a test procedure I can check it.

Comment: @mMontu, you're right, I'll try with the latest version. Thanks the great windows support for other software, it's a pain to constantly keep your software up-to-date.

Comment: @mMontu, it's the same behavior with 7.4. You can see my `.vimrc` file [here](https://gist.github.com/ShabbyX/3691170#file-vimrc-L80). Do `:Shabi` to enable the mapping and you can experiment. If I comment out the `cnoremap`s, and add `set imcmdline` and `set imsearch=-1` above `(where `iminsert` is set), the behavior is that the mapping is correct in search, but not command line

Comment: In either case, the character followed by `f` is stored as the original in the macro and when played back it doesn't use the mapping.

Comment: I did a quick test and noticed that the mapping doesn't work with macros indeed. Maybe it is because I'm not used, but I found your mappings very confusing. On `function SwapKeys()` I would unmap the keys if `a:do` is 0, instead of the mapping the key to itself.